# How can I fit Clothes to a Body?

Tags: mesh

[image]

I want to fit these clothes onto the base mesh (mesh has no rig). How do I do that without breaking the mesh entirely?

Comment: I don't know how you could do it without deforming the mesh, but maybe you could use tricks like Mesh Deform modifier to make it easier

Comment: oh, what I meant by "deforming the mesh" is "not break the mesh entirely". Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's an easy way to do it, I would do it manually, but you could try to do it with a *Mesh Deform* modifier (I tried with an armature then apply it but it was not as good):

- Create a low-poly cage around the object you want to deform. In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display* > *Maximum Draw Type*, choose *Wire* to make it transparent.

[image]

- Give the high-poly a *Mesh Deform* modifier with the low-poly as *Object*, click on the *Bind* button.

[image]

- Deform the low-poly cage.

[image]

- When you're glad, select the high-poly and click on the *Apply* button.
- Make some corrections in *Edit* mode with the *Proportional Editing* mode enabled.

[image]